# jquery ordering and group li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, grouping, html-lists

Let's say I have a list of items under a div or UL.  I want to take all the list items with the same title attribute and wrap a UL around it.  The next part though is that I want that UL to be under the LI with the same attribute.  So, I'm trying to group basically.

So.... I start with.....

```
<li>Insurance</li>
<li>Education</li>
<li>Sports</li>
<li>Construction</li>
<li title ="Insurance">Malpractice</li>
<li title ="Construction">Carpentry</li>
<li title ="Education">College</li>
<li title ="Insurance">Automobile</li>
<li title ="Education">High School</li>
<li title ="Construction">Iron Worker</li>
```

and I want to get to......

```
<li>Insurance
    <ul>
         <li title ="Insurance">Malpractice</li>
         <li title ="Insurance">Automobile</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>Education
    <ul>
         <li title ="Education">College</li>
         <li title ="Education">High School</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>Sports</li>
<li>Construction
    <ul>
         <li title ="Construction">Carpentry</li>
         <li title ="Construction">Iron Worker</li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Obviously new to the jquery and javascript world so I'm trying to wrap my brain around this.

Comment: Where is this information coming from?

Comment: What you want is not valid HTML. Each nested `<ul>` tag must be inside the parent `<li>` (like `<li>Insurance<ul> (...)</ul></li>`).

Comment: Hah, you're right!!!!!!   I was so busy cutitng and pasting and setting up the scenario that I COMPLETELY screwed up the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first we fetch all items without title attribute
var topLevel = $('li:not([title])');

// for each of those...
topLevel.each(function() {
  var li = $(this),
      // ... we get its text ...
      title = li.text(),
      // ... and other li elements with the corresponding title
      children = $('li[title="' + title + '"]');

  // if there are any...
  if (children.length > 0) {
    // ... create an empty list ...
    var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
    // ... fill it and ...
    children.appendTo(ul);
    // ... append it to the original li element
    ul.appendTo(li);
  }
});
```

jQuery documentation: [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/),  [`[title]`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: i tried the not([title]) approach as well, but why doesn't this fiddle work? http://jsfiddle.net/jbkQP/

Comment: Because you selected MooTools and not jQuery as library to include ;-)

Comment: never mind me, i was looking at the right hand side instead of the console, arrgh

Comment: note that I didn't have valid HTML in my first post... that might make things different.  sorry!  rough morning.

Answer (score 4):

**Input:**

```
<div id="stuffs">
    <li>Insurance</li>
    <li>Education</li>
    <li>Sports</li>
    <li>Construction</li>
    <li title ="Insurance">Malpractice</li>
    <li title ="Construction">Carpentry</li>
    <li title ="Education">College</li>
    <li title ="Insurance">Automobile</li>
    <li title ="Education">High School</li>
    <li title ="Construction">Iron Worker</li>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
​$("#stuffs li").each(function(){
    $("#stuffs li[title='"+$(this).text()+"']").appendTo($(this)).wrapAll("<ul />");
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Output:**

```
<div id="stuffs">
  <ul>
    <li>Insurance
        <ul>
            <li title="Insurance">Malpractice</li>
            <li title="Insurance">Automobile</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Education
        <ul>
            <li title="Education">College</li>
            <li title="Education">High School</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Sports</li>
    <li>Construction
        <ul>
            <li title="Construction">Carpentry</li>
            <li title="Construction">Iron Worker</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Smile** :-)

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdpDW/)

Comment: note that the HTML i needed for the final output was invalid.  that might change your solution....

Comment: Then use `appendTo` instead of `insertAfter`. I updated my code.

Comment: Yes, that's really a nice solution. +1

Comment: I like your solution, but aren't LIs only valid in a OL or UL?

Comment: Yes it is. But he didn't wrap them in the question so didn't I. But, okay, let's wrap it! :)

Comment: Yes, I assumed that people would know that I had a <UL> around the <LI> elements.  I should have just put it in.

Comment: VERY NICE!  Thank you so much!  I've actually run into needing something like this a couple times.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$('#id li:not([title])').append('<ul />');

$('#id li[title]').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#id li:contains(' + $(this).attr('title') + ') ul');
})
```

[A demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4KRU/)