# render ul li list according to their parent jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a dynamic array that can be empty or can be like the following with items having different parents. You never how many items there can be with many type of `parent` subjects. The trick is to group the items according to their parents into a UL LI list

```
{
  "parent": "Vegetables", 
  "title": "Carrots" 
},
{
  "parent": "Fruit", 
  "title": "Apple" 
},
{
  "parent": "Vegetables", 
  "title": "Lettuce" 
},
{
  "parent": "Fruit", 
  "title": "Banana" 
}
```

This is an example of the following list

```
<ul>Fruit
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li> 
</ul>

<ul>Vegetables
  <li>Lettuce</li>
  <li>Carrots</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Can the solution be in angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ordering and group li elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417325/jquery-ordering-and-group-li-elements)

Comment: I am looking for jquery solutions or javascript. What I am building is really small so I am not using any framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should group the items list by it's parent name. Then, loop through the grouped items and print them out.

p/s: Your expected output structure is not seems right.

```
<ul>Fruit</ul>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Banana</li>
```

Did you mean:

```
<ul>
    <li>Fruit

        <ul>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
var items = [{
    "parent": "Vegetables",
    "title": "Carrots"
}, {
    "parent": "Fruit",
    "title": "Apple"
}, {
    "parent": "Vegetables",
    "title": "Lettuce"
}, {
    "parent": "Fruit",
    "title": "Banana"
}];

var groups = {};
items.forEach(item => {
    if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(item.parent)) {
        groups[item.parent] = [];
    }

    groups[item.parent].push(item.title);
});

var result = '';
for (var name in groups) {
    result += '<ul>' + name + '</ul>';

    groups[name].forEach(item => result += '<li>' + item + '</li>');
}

container.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<pre id="container"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think is the solution you want

```
Script:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array_list = [{
  "parent": "Vegetables", 
  "title": "Carrots" 
},
{
  "parent": "Fruit", 
  "title": "Apple" 
},
{
  "parent": "Vegetables", 
  "title": "Lettuce" 
},
{
  "parent": "Fruit", 
  "title": "Banana" 
}];
var veg = array_list[0].parent;
var fruit = array_list[1].parent;
for(i=0;i<array_list.length;i++){
    if(array_list[i].parent == veg){
           $(".type").append("<li>"+array_list[i].parent+"</li><li>"+array_list[i].title+"</li>");
    }else if(array_list[i].parent == fruit){
           $(".type").append("<li>"+array_list[i].parent+"</li><li>"+array_list[i].title+"</li>");
    }
}
});
</script>

HTML:

<ul class="type"></ul>

Now by add style to the list as you like.

Hope this is helpful.
```